# Workaround for Laravel 4.2 to use array to build where()

Tags: php, laravel-4

In Laravel 5.2, you can pass an array of field names and values to the where() object and it works: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses

It looks like this was introduced in 5.x as it fails in 4.2. It seems 4.2 requires using one where() for each field and value combo.

Is there a way to emulate this functionality? I can't think of anything specific at the moment.

I need this for a function that takes a dynamic array and passes it to the where(). This function is used in multiple places for multiple purposes in a piece of software, so a hardcoded list isn't viable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try this. This is what i did in my 5.x project and hopefully it also works in 4.2

I also based in this [link](http://www.franzliedke.de/blog/laravel-4-model-query-scopes.html)

In your model, put this function.

```
public function scopeCustomWhereClause($query,$array)
{

    for ($i=0; $i < count($array) ; $i++) { 
        $query = $query->where( $array[$i][0], $array[$i][1],  $array[$i][2]);

    }

    return $query;
}
```

to use the created function:

```
$array = array(
            ['status', '=', '1'],
            ['subscribed', '<>', '1']
        );

$users = User::customWhereClause($array)->get();
```

Hope this works.

Note: If your want to make this function usable in every model, use traits and then call it in your models.

Comment: Would this re-run the query multiple times? It looks a bit odd to overwrite a variable during each iteration of the loop and then return it.

Comment: in my case, the query concatenates.

Comment: @Lawrence I modified the code a little and already tested it and its working.

Comment: You are awesome Miggy! So I guess I just have to do a class extends on the Eloquent class to put it all together?

Comment: you can literally copy and paste it in you desired model where you want to use that function or if you want to use it in all of your models you can use traits since every model extends on Eloquent

Comment: I'm integrating with WHMCS so my code right now looks like this

Comment: `<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
use Carbon\Carbon as Carbon;

Capsule::table('mod_addonexample')->where('module', 'addonexample')->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(60))->delete();
?>`

Comment: And Capsule\Manager pulls in Eloquent :)
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

Comment: in that case you can use traits in your capsule\Manager

Comment: Never used traits before and the docs are a bit confusing. Any pointers?

Comment: you can use this for your reference https://www.sitepoint.com/using-traits-in-php-5-4/